# Google Analytics cookie domain affects other cookies

Tags: google-analytics, jquery-cookie

In Google Analytics code I have something like the following in order to track the main domain `www.mysite.com` as well as subdomains `forms.mysite.com`, etc...

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', ".mysite.com"]);
```

I have another application running in a subdirectory `www.mysite.com/app` of this site that uses cookies on `www.mysite.com` for storing temporary user data.  These cookies are set client side using the [jQuery-Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.  As far as I can tell the plugin is setting the domain as `www.mysite.com` while the site-wide GA analytics is setting its cookies as `.mysite.com`.  However the plugin is unable to delete the cookies that it has set and the reason is that the domain doesn't match the one that is actually stored in the browser.  Using [Chrome Web Developer Extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) shows that the domain has actually been stored as `.www.mysite.com` and the deletion failure makes sense to me.

I suspect that the GA setDomainName directive/command is affecting the jQuery plugin logic.  Is this the expected browser behavior or should I search for bugs in the jQuery-Cookie plugin source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_setDomainName should *only* affect Google Analytics cookies. GA should not have any impact on other cookies being set:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName